# Different runtime duration with `go run` and `go build`

Tags: go

Why does the runtime of my program change when I use `go run` vs `go build` and executing my program?

I'm using the `time` package to measure the time elapsed during program execution, and I stumbled upon this behaviour.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "time"
)

func sumInt(b []byte, c chan int) {
    sum := 0
    for _, num := range b {
        sum += int(num)
    }
    c <- sum
}

func main() {
    start := time.Now()

    dat, err := ioutil.ReadFile("nums.txt")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    partSum1 := make(chan int)
    partSum2 := make(chan int)

    go sumInt(dat[:len(dat)/2], partSum1)
    go sumInt(dat[len(dat)/2:], partSum2)

    sum := <-partSum1 + <-partSum2
    fmt.Println(sum)

    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Printf("Elapsed %s\n", elapsed)
}
```

```
❱ go run runtime.go 
2502263
Elapsed 133.893µs
❱ go build runtime.go 
❱ ./runtime 
2502263
Elapsed 402.435µs
❱
```

Comment: I would expect a difference but would expect `go run` to take longer than `go build`, and definitely not a 3 times difference. Maybe it has something to do with caching. Waiting for the answer

Comment: "Measuring" execution time with the time package will never yield meaningful results.

Comment: A single run with an execution time on the order of microseconds is not very telling... you'd need to do hundreds of runs and average the results to get meaningful data.

Comment: Use the `-x` flag and see everything that each command is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Go, we don't favor meaningless microbenchmarks. If you are going to run a benchmark, use the Go `testing` package.

For example,

Output:

```
$ go test sum_test.go -bench=. -benchmem
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkSum-8    500000    2905 ns/op    4288 B/op    3 allocs/op
$
```

`sum_test.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

func sumInt(b []byte, c chan int) {
    sum := 0
    for _, num := range b {
        sum += int(num)
    }
    c <- sum
}

func BenchmarkSum(b *testing.B) {
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        dat := make([]byte, 4*1024)
        partSum1 := make(chan int)
        partSum2 := make(chan int)
        go sumInt(dat[:len(dat)/2], partSum1)
        go sumInt(dat[len(dat)/2:], partSum2)
        sum := <-partSum1 + <-partSum2
        _ = sum
    }
}
```